# Get channelId, it always returns "UC"

Tags: youtube-api

(I wrote "Hello", but it gets removed.)

I'm using the youtube api from an android application.

I was getting the channelId from a "channel" search by looking at id.channelid. Now it seems to have been changed to snippet.channelid.

But the field value is always "UC". ???

The code:

```
YouTube.Search.List search = youtube.search().list("id,snippet");
search.setKey("my key");
search.setQ("whatever channel name");
search.setType("channel");
search.setFields("items(snippet(channelId))");
search.setMaxResults((long)1);
SearchListResponse searchResponseC = search.execute();
List<SearchResult> searchResultListC = searchResponseC.getItems();
String channelid = ((SearchResult)searchResultListC.get(0)).getSnippet().getChannelId();
```

Now channelid value is "UC".

Also, I'm not sure if the line search.setType("channel"); has any effect.

Help, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a known issue with the V3 api this week.

https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4971